# Swift - Using a UISwitch to change Pin Color

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch, mkpinannotationview

I want to change the pin color from Red to Purple once the switch has been turned on. So far I have tried:

```
@IBAction func SwitchChanged(_ sender: Any){
  if LegacySwitch.isOn == true {
   annotation.pinTintColor = .purple
  } else {
   annotation.pinTintColor = .red
  }
}
```

My switch is connected with:

```
@IBOutlet weak var LegacySwitch: UISwitch!
```

I created my pin in my ViewDidLoad. The coordinates of the pin come from another ViewController.

```
//Map Stuff
    let Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    annotation.coordinate = Coordinates
    LocationMap.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    self.LocationMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

When ever I run the app, the pin continues to be red. The Action is encountered as I used a breakpoint to tell me it ran.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention, I created the annotation variable above the ViewDidLoad.

```
var annotation = MyPointAnnotation()
```

I also have a MKPointAnnotation Class

```
class MyPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var pinTintColor: UIColor?
}
```

**Things that did not work:**

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    if LegacySwitch.isOn {
        annotationView.pinTintColor = .purple
    } else {
        annotationView.pinTintColor = .red
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: It's because you can't simply add anything *defined* in viewDidLoad (including "annotation") and expect to reference it everywhere in the view controller. Either define it as a global variable, or loop through the annotations collection in  `LocationMap` (if possible) to change all of them. This is the same thing with any subview.

Comment: I have it created as a variable above the viewDidLoad. I edited my question to reflect this just now.

Comment: `if LegacySwitch.isOn == true` is redundant. No need to include `== true`. Also a ternary operator would fit better than if conditional there. `annotation.pinTintColor = LegacySwitch.isOn ? .purple : .red`

Comment: Have you verified that your `SwitchChanged` code is executing? The code looks good - provided pinTintColor is the correct thing to set. BTW, naming conventions for Swift suggest to have a lower-cease first letter for function and control names.

Comment: @dfd The switch changed code is working. The pin is just not changing color.

Comment: Looks like @Matt has the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Distinguish between:

- An **annotation**: a lightweight bundle of characteristics
- An **annotation view**: what you *see*, supplied on the basis of the annotation through a call to the map view delegate's [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview).

You are changing the former but not the latter. All the action in that regard happens in `mapView(_:viewFor:)`, but you have not shown that  — nor is there any particular reason why it would be called just because you change a property of an annotation sitting off in an instance variable somewhere. You need to *replace* the annotation in the *map*, so as to get the annotation view to be regenerated.

Comment: I looked up how to use mapView, but I'm not sure I used it correctly. Check my question for what I used

Comment: So what on earth is MyPointAnnotation even for?

Comment: While trying to change pin color, someone suggested I create MyPointAnnotation.

Comment: Anyway, now that you have shown that you are trying to set the color in `mapView(_:viewFor:)`, all you have to do is set a breakpoint at the start and walk through it step by step and see what's happening. Does the `if` clause ever take you into the `.purple` branch? I'm betting it never does, because you've already created this annotation view and you are not doing anything that cause it to be regenerated (as I said in my answer already).

Comment: What does "yes" mean? If you are in `mapView(_:viewFor:)` and you go into the `.purple` branch, you get a purple pin, don't you?